# Replacing joins with Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel, eloquent

I have created simple permissions system in Laravel. Each user might be connected with any number of permissions (many to many) and those permissions are organized in groups (one to many).

For example, there is a group called `customers` with permissions such as `create`, `read`, `update` and `delete`. Yes, CRUD :)

Now I need to check if user is has been allowed to do certain action, for example updating customers. I created a method for that in `User` model and it's called like this:

```
$user->can('customer.update')
```

As you can see, the first part is a group and the second is a permission. I managed to make this method use work with SQL joins, but I wonder if it can be done better, with Eloquent.

Here's what I did in User model:

```
public function can($action) {
    $chunks = explode('.', $action);

    if (count($chunks) !== 2) {
        return false;
    }

    list($group, $permission) = $chunks;

    $matches = $this::permissions()
        ->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'permissions.group_id')
        ->where('groups.key', $group)
        ->where('permissions.key', $permission)
        ->count();

    return $matches > 0;
}
```

The query that is being run is (for user with ID = 19):

```
select count(*) as aggregate
from `permissions`
inner join `permission_user` on `permissions`.`id` = `permission_user`.`permission_id`
inner join `groups` on `groups`.`id` = `permissions`.`group_id`
where `permission_user`.`user_id` = '19'
and `groups`.`key` = 'customers'
and `permissions`.`key` = 'update'
```

Can I do better, with pure Eloquent?

Comment: Replace joins with relations, which are more flexible. I have all relations defined, but don't know how to use two levels in one query.

Comment: Edit the question and add the relations, then I'll show you how.

Comment: A described them in the first sentence.

Comment: I asked you to show them. Anyway, below the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
return $user->permissions()->where('key', $permission)
  ->whereHas('group', function ($q) use ($group) {
      $q->where('key', $group);
  })->exists();
```

Comment: As I said, permissions and groups are in one to many relation.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Change `groups` to `group` if that's the relation name, that's all.